# Why the text rendering is different between "default text" and "user typed text" in UWP TextBox control?

Tags: xaml, uwp, textbox, winui-3

You can see that the 2nd TextBox (user typed text) text is wider than the 1st TextBox text.

[image]

I found this in WinUI 3 but got the same result in UWP. I couldn't reproduce this in WPF.

This is the XAML.

```xml
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Text="Default text" />
    <TextBox
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Text="TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest" />
    <TextBlock
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Text="Typed text" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

My question is in the title but I'd like to know if there is a way to make them identically.

**UPDATE**

Thanks @Niko Zhu ! I tried your suggestion and as you mentioned, this seems to be an **IME**? or **Google Japanese Input** problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the text rendering is different between "default text" and "user typed text" in UWP TextBox control?

I could reproduce this problem with chinses keyboard input, and it looks [IME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/input-method-editors) problem that uppercase characters are larger than the default. Please use US keyboard to replace, it will solve the problem.